# Way to determine checkbox checked in react (useState)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is my first time to develop a react application. I tried to implement checkboxes in each row of a table and check which of the rows are selected.

I used `useState` hook to make checked and onChange events, but seems the values are not refreshing when I check then uncheck the checkbox.

I would like to ask how to add a logic to remove the unticked values on the hooks.

T1
Checkbox A- Checked
Checkbox B- Checked
CheckedMap- A,B

T2
Checkbox B- Unchecked
CheckedMap- A,B // Unticked Checkbox B is also stored in CheckedMap

Thank you for your help.

```
export default function({ infinite }) {
  const [checkedMap, setCheckedMap] = useState(new Map());
}

const handleCheckedChange = transaction_seq => {
    let modifiedMap = checkedMap;
    modifiedMap.set(transaction_seq, !checkedMap.get(transaction_seq));
    setCheckedMap(modifiedMap);
  };

const columns = [
    {
      Header: "Transaction(s)",
      className: "left",
      columns: [
        {
          id: "checkbox",
          accessor: "checkbox",
          Cell: ({ row }) => {
            return (
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                className="checkbox"
                checked={checkedMap.get(row.original.transaction_seq)}
                onChange={() =>
                  handleCheckedChange(row.original.transaction_seq)
                }
```

Comment: Is this really your code? It does not look like a valid decleration of a react function component.

Comment: In pre-react times this had been done with one line of the code...

Answer (score 21):

This is the way how to use controlled checkbox with react `useState` hook.

```js
const { useState } = React; // --> for inline use
// import React, { useState } from 'react';  // --> for real project


const App = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
  const handleClick = () => setChecked(!checked)
  
  return <input onClick={handleClick} checked={checked} type="checkbox" />
};


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: what if i have 30 checkboxes? Or the data is coming from an external API?

Comment: Please, have a look on this answer for dynamic checkbox data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020545/limit-number-of-checkboxes-selected-and-save-value/63021381#63021381

Comment: it is better to use onChange because you may see this error
You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`

Answer (score 1):

You may get an error using onClick for the function. Instead using onChange:

```
    import { useState} from "react";

    export default function App() {
      const [checked, setChecked] = useState<boolean>(true);
      
      return (
        <input name="checked" type="checkbox" checked={checked} 
          onChange={e => setChecked(!checked)} />
      )
    }
```

Comment: Really simple and clean!

Answer (score 1):

You got an event object when you use onChange. Use that event to check if the checkbox is checked or not

```
//here, you got access to event object
onChange={(e) =>
  handleCheckedChange(e, row.original.transaction_seq)
}
```

Then, in your function just use that event to check the status

```
const handleCheckedChange = (e, transaction_seq) => {
  if(e.target.checked == true){
    //do something
  }
  if(e.target.checked != true){
    //do something else
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the check status in map and then decide whether to set the value or delete it

```
const handleCheckedChange = transaction_seq => {
    let modifiedMap = checkedMap;
    if(checkedMap.get(transaction_seq)) {
        modifiedMap.delete(transaction_seq)
    } else {
        modifiedMap.set(transaction_seq, true);
    }
    setCheckedMap(modifiedMap);
  };
```