# useReducer and useEffect hooks to fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am experimenting with react hooks, but I am getting a bit confused on how to use `useEffect` and `useReducer`.

I have a simple page with few checkboxes, on change of each checkbox I should re-query the api to load new data.

My idea was to code the component as follow:

```
export const Page: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  // state to manage the list returned by the api
  const [list, setList] = useState<any[]>([]);
  // this should manage the state related to the checkboxes
  const [checkboxesState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialCheckboxesState);

  useEffect(() => {
    // load data from api
    loadProducts(checkboxesState);
  }, [checkboxesState]); // my idea here is that when checkboxesState changes, it should trigger the 'useEffect' hook
}
```

Now regarding the useReducer

```
// initial state
const initialFiltersState: CheckboxesState = {
  country: [], // array of strings for countries ie ['USA', 'Brazil', 'India']
};

function reducer(
  checkboxesState: CheckboxesState,
  action: { type: string; value: string; checked: boolean }
) {
  const index = checkboxesState[action.type].indexOf(action.value);
  // if checkbox is ticked and it's not already present in the array, insert it
  if (action.checked && index === -1) {
    checkboxesState[action.type].push(action.value);
  } else if (!action.checked && index > -1) {
    // if it's present and we are unchecking it, remove it from the array
    checkboxesState[action.type].splice(index, 1);
  }

  // TODO: this is not the best way to handle reload. I don't want to do it here, this should just trigger the useEffect
  loadProducts(productFilters);
  return checkboxesState;
}

// this is the handler for checkbox changes
const onChangeHandler = (event: any): void => {
  dispatch({
    type: event.target.name, // eg. country
    value: event.target.value, // eg. Australia
    checked: event.target.checked,// bool
  });
};
```

Now I know it might be something stupid I am doing, but I have been stuck on this for quite a while. Any idea why the useEffect is not called when the `checkboxesState` changes? Or am I completely off track?

I have tried to pass `JSON.stringify(checkboxesState)` to useEffect, but no luck either.

My component has a bit more stuff in it that are not relevant, so I tried to put here only the code relevant to the specific task. I Hope I explained myself clearly

Comment: I have a working checkbox useReducer example here on stackoverflow. Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020545/limit-number-of-checkboxes-selected-and-save-value/63021381#63021381

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not updating the state correctly.

The reason why `useEffect` is not triggered when the state is updated is because you are **mutating the state directly**. You are returning the same state object from the reducer. So, as far as React is concerned, the reducer function doesn't update the state when it is called. As a result, `useEffect` is not triggered again.

You need to return a new state object from the reducer so that React knows that state has been updated by the reducer. Modify your reducer to return a new object every time it updates the state.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use thunk actions, these actions always have access to most recent state and can dispatch multiple actions. Thunk actions can even call other thunk actions and wait for them (if the thunk action **returns** a promise): `thunkAction(arg)(dispatch,getState).then(thunkActionResult=>otherStuff)`.

Thunks are well documented and easily recognized by other developers.

Thunk is a middleware of Redux but can be applied to useReducer with a custom hook:

```js
const { useRef, useState } = React;
//custom hook, you can define in different file
const compose = (...fns) =>
  fns.reduce((result, fn) => (...args) =>
    fn(result(...args))
  );
const mw = () => (next) => (action) => next(action);
const createMiddleware = (...middlewareFunctions) => (
  store
) =>
  compose(
    ...middlewareFunctions
      .concat(mw)
      .reverse()
      .map((fn) => fn(store))
  );
const useMiddlewareReducer = (
  reducer,
  initialState,
  middleware = () => (b) => (c) => b(c)
) => {
  const stateContainer = useRef(initialState);
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const dispatch = (action) => {
    const next = (action) => {
      stateContainer.current = reducer(
        stateContainer.current,
        action
      );
      return setState(stateContainer.current);
    };
    const store = {
      dispatch,
      getState: () => stateContainer.current,
    };
    return middleware(store)(next)(action);
  };
  return [state, dispatch];
};

//middleware
const thunkMiddleWare = ({ getState, dispatch }) => (
  next
) => (action) =>
  typeof action === 'function'
    ? action(dispatch, getState)
    : next(action);
const logMiddleware = ({ getState }) => (next) => (
  action
) => {
  console.log('in log middleware', action, getState());
  Promise.resolve().then(() =>
    console.log('after action:', action.type, getState())
  );
  return next(action);
};
//your actions
const init = { value: 'A' };
const TOGGLE = 'TOGGLE';
const later = () =>
  new Promise((r) => setTimeout(() => r(), 500));
const otherThunk = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'not relevant action form otherTunk' });
  console.log('in other thunk, state is:', getState());
  //note that I am returning a promise
  return later();
};
const thunkToggle = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  //dispatching other thunk and waiting for it to finish
  otherThunk()(dispatch, getState).then(() =>
    dispatch({ type: TOGGLE })
  );
};
//your component code
const reducer = (state, { type }) => {
  console.log(`in reducer action type: ${type}`);
  //toggle state.value between A and B
  if (type === TOGGLE) {
    return { value: state.value === 'A' ? 'B' : 'A' };
  }
  return state;
};
const middleware = createMiddleware(
  thunkMiddleWare,
  logMiddleware
);
const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useMiddlewareReducer(
    reducer,
    init,
    middleware
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(thunkToggle())}>
        toggle
      </button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

With thunk you can move the logic out of your component and just do `dispatch(fetchData(args))`