# Set array from selected checkboxes

Tags: reactjs

Im kinda new at react, so im looking to get a push in the right direction here. What i am trying to do is onChange of the checkbox, i need to query which checkboxes are checked and create an array with the selected values. Current code below

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';


function Formats(props) {
  const FormatsApi = 'props.serverUrl'

  // Get data from api
  const [formats, setFormats ] = useState([])

  // Need to query checkboxes and set array with values
  function handleChange(e) {
      // set array here
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(FormatsApi)
      console.log(result.data)
      setFormats(result.data)
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="row">
      {formats.map(format => (
        <div className="col-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end" key={format.key_string}>
          <label className="mr-2 mb-0">{format.key_string}</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name={format.key_string} value={format.id} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
      ))}
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Formats
```

Comment: This looked like a good solution http://react.tips/checkboxes-in-react-16/

Comment: Does this answer cover your needs maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020545/limit-number-of-checkboxes-selected-and-save-value/63021381#63021381

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple like the following to store the selected checkboxes in the state should work.

```
// create a state variable to store the checkbox selection
const [checkSelection, setCheckSelection] = useState([]);

function handleChange(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.checked) {
        setCheckSelection([...checkSelection, e.target.value]);
    } else {
        const newArr = checkSelection.filter((item) => item !== e.target.value);
        setCheckSelection(newArr);
    }
}
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-wildflower-iiigl?file=/src/App.js) here.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to maintain an array of visibility somewhere... which you can keep updated on each click on each checkbox

relevant **JS**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import axios from "axios";

const mockData = {
  data: [
    { key_string: "1", id: 1 },
    { key_string: "2", id: 2 },
    { key_string: "3", id: 3 },
    { key_string: "4", id: 4 }
  ]
};

function Formats(props) {
  const FormatsApi = "props.serverUrl";

  // Get data from api
  const [formats, setFormats] = useState([]);
  const [formatsCheckBoxRecord, setFormatsCheckBoxRecord] = useState([]);

  // Need to query checkboxes and set array with values
  function handleChange(e) {
    // set array here
    let beforeUpdateArray = [...formatsCheckBoxRecord];
    let relevantEntry = beforeUpdateArray.find(
      x => x.id.toString() === e.target.value.toString()
    );
    let relevantEntryIndex = beforeUpdateArray.findIndex(
      x => x.id.toString() === e.target.value.toString()
    );
    relevantEntry.checkStatus = !relevantEntry.checkStatus;
    beforeUpdateArray[relevantEntryIndex] = relevantEntry;
    setFormatsCheckBoxRecord(beforeUpdateArray);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const result = mockData; // await axios(FormatsApi);
        console.log(result.data);
        setFormats(result.data);
        let formatsCheckBoxRecordArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
          formatsCheckBoxRecordArray.push({
            id: result.data[i].id,
            checkStatus: false
          });
        }
        setFormatsCheckBoxRecord(formatsCheckBoxRecordArray);
        // console.log(formatsCheckBoxRecordArray);
      }, 20);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="contianer">
      <div className="row">
        {formats && formats.length > 0
          ? formats.map(format => (
              <div
                className="col-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end"
                key={format.key_string}
              >
                <label className="mr-2 mb-0">{format.key_string}</label>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name={format.key_string}
                  value={format.id}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </div>
            ))
          : null}
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        {formatsCheckBoxRecord && formatsCheckBoxRecord.length > 0
          ? formatsCheckBoxRecord.map(val => (
              <div>
                {val.id} [{val.checkStatus.toString()}]
              </div>
            ))
          : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Formats;
```

working [example on stakblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gdjlzt?file=src%2FApp.js)